# How to do image zoom out and zoom in with cursor attribute?

Tags: html

I have a scenario of opening an image in a new window. There i need to add zoom in and zoom out option for the images which are all big.

[Here](http://images.hellokids.com/_uploads/_tiny_galerie/200901/popeye-the-sailor-coloring-page08-source_pbs.jpg) is one example.
I want to know, how they are doing zoom in and zoom out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do a "custom" zoom in/out, you could use some JS to set the zoom css prop i.e.:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/65FH5/

Answer (score 2):

It's just an image, there's no magic. Any zoom function you may see there is a **feature of your browser.**